# mysql NOW() + $seconds php?

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to use mysqls `NOW()` function and add seconds to or from it?

Like so;

```
$q = $dbc -> prepare ("UPDATE account SET time = NOW() + $seconds WHERE id = ?");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want to do this in MySql, you can either use

```
DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL $seconds SECOND)
```

or

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP() + $seconds
```

### Source

- [unix_timestamp()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)
- [date_add()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)
- [INTERVAL $seconds](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/expressions.html#temporal-intervals)

Answer (score 1):

You can add seconds to it with [`DATE_ADD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add):

```
$q = $dbc -> prepare ("UPDATE account SET time = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL $seconds SECONDS) WHERE id = ?");
```

Comment: Beware though that if I get $seconds = "little johhny tables;" into your PHP, you've a gaping hole. You probably want to use your DB-layers placeholder system (the ?) instead of simply injecting $seconds.

Answer (score 1):

```
$q = $dbc -> prepare ("UPDATE account SET time = date_add(NOW() + INTERVAL $seconds SECOND) WHERE id = ?");
```

Answer (score -1):

**No** it is not possible.

You can just do:

```
$time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+2 seconds"));
$q = $dbc->prepare ("UPDATE account SET time = '$time' WHERE id = ?");
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know your exact dbc class usage, but most probably, you want to simply add another parameter:

```
$q = $dbc->prepare ("UPDATE account SET time = NOW() + ? WHERE id = ?");
$q->execute($seconds, $id);
```